# mysql dump - Unknown database 'mysqldump'

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to export a database from c# using mysqldump.

When I run it i get this message: Unknown database 'mysqldump' when selecting the database.
I can't find the solution.

```
public static void mysqlBackup()
{
    try
    {
        //string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

        Log.Info("Starting MySQL dump");


        Process MySqlDump = new Process();
        MySqlDump.StartInfo.FileName = @"mysqldump.exe";
        MySqlDump.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        MySqlDump.StartInfo.Arguments = 
           "mysqldump -uroot -p******** b3 >"+ 
           " C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/temp/backups/backup.sql";
        MySqlDump.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false; 
        MySqlDump.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

        MySqlDump.Start();

        MySqlDump.WaitForExit();
        MySqlDump.Close();

        Log.Info("Successfull created");
    }

    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Unable to write the database file" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I tried to remove the mysqldump from the arguments kinda the same problem.

Comment: What happens when you remove mysqldump from the arguments?

Comment: if you remove the process from the equation does it work?

Comment: @both mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirection operator `>` is not an argument to `mysqldump`.  When you execute it on the command line, it's being interpreted by the command line itself, not by mysqldump.  You have two choices here:

1. Use the `--result-file` option as others have mentioned
2. Capture the stdout of the process and do what you like with the output by setting the `RedirectStandardOutput` property of `StartInfo` to be `true`.  After this, you can read from the `StandardOutput` stream of the process.

Comment: Thank you that was the solution!

Comment: +1 thank you for this...

On a side note I got the following error when trying to store the mysqldump command line statement in quotes so that I could log the command and also execute it...

`mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database '>' when selecting the database`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the name of the database you want to dump as the first argument.  Thanks to nathan it goes after `--databases` at the end.

Comment: It goes after the options [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
MySqlDump.StartInfo.Arguments = "-u root -p *** database_name --result-file [path]\backup.sql";
```

You don't need to specify mysqldump again in the command either (not that it should make much difference).

Answer (score 0):

The Mysql documentation states there are 3 ways to use the mysqldump command:

```
shell> mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
shell> mysqldump [options] --databases db_name ...
shell> mysqldump [options] --all-databases
```

Ensure the command works fine via your command line. If it does that execute that command directly within your code. If that works then start extracting your arguments and replacing them with your own parameters within code.

Basically you want to get as basic as possible and work back up from there.

If the file works on the command line, try this:

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{        
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"mysqldump.exe -u root -p *** --database b3 -r test.sql"; <~~~ note the change here
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
}
```

The file will be dumped to your project folders bin/debug or bin/release folder unless you change that code.

**Here is your edited method:**

public static void mysqlBackup()
    {
        try
        {

```
        //string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

        Log.Info("Starting MySQL dump");


    using(Process MySqlDump = new Process()
    {
        MySqlDump.StartInfo.FileName = @"mysqldump.exe";
        MySqlDump.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        MySqlDump.StartInfo.Arguments = "-uroot -p******** b3 --result-file=C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/temp/backups/backup.sql";
        MySqlDump.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false; 
        MySqlDump.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false; //You can redirect this as mention in other answers 

        MySqlDump.Start();

        MySqlDump.WaitForExit();
        MySqlDump.Close();
    }
   Log.Info("Successfully created");
    }

    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Unable to write the database file" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: when i type that directly in the command line it works but when i run it from c# i get that message above.

Comment: That will give a crash because you have to add p.StartInfo.Arguments. It will read the database but it appears in the console window not in a backup.sql file

Comment: I've run programs with arguments before without using the StartInfo.Arguments param, so I am not sure why it would crash... But if it is outputting the data to a console window then we know that the bulk of the command is working and it is the redirection that is causing the issue. Are you still getting an error Couldn't find table: ">"?

Comment: No i get the database output in the console in stead of in a backup.sql file

Comment: If that doesnt work, you can also try --result-file=file_name instead of -r